# Obtain package name of extended class

Tags: java, package

Let's say that we have a base class:

```
package mobi.hsz.app.plugin;
abstract class Plugin {}
```

And extended class:

```
package 3rd.party.plugin;
ThirdPartyPlugin extends Plugin {}
```

Is it possible to obtain package name of extended class in base class ?

I have to get in my abstract class simple string

```
3rd.party.plugin
```

Comment: What if multiple classes extend `Plugin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little reflection code should work here:

```
getClass().getPackage().getName()
```

The `getClass()` method gets the `Class` object for the instance, `getPackage()` gets the `Package` object, and [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getName%28%29) returns the fully-qualified package name.

Java's polymorphism will ensure that the proper `Class` object (here, `ThirdPartyPlugin`) is returned from `getClass()`.

Comment: That's it ! In my head there was something that told me it will return 'base' package name. Thank you !

Comment: This creates a circular dependency - subclass depends on superclass which references subclass - yuk (not worth a -1 as it is technically correct)

Comment: @earcam: No, the superclass doesn't actually *reference* the subclass. It's just getting information about the actual type of an object. It's really *not* a circular dependency.

Comment: @earcam Not quite.  Here, `Plugin` will have the package name in a `String`, but so far it's not making decisions using the details of the subclass or the subclass's package.

Comment: @Jon Skeet and @rgettman - Unless you pass the subclass in via a method such as `void <T extends Plugin> provide(T plugin)` you will be creating a circular dependency.  The OPs interface does not specify that.  Regardless you need a collaborating class to wire up this for you (nothing wrong with that), but this collaborator will be subject to the open-close principle unless using some form of dependency inversion.  My point was to avoid circular dependencies **and** violation of OCP, as per my answer.

Comment: @earcam: I don't think we have *nearly* enough context to say that there's a circular dependency. Just passing in a value as a `Plugin` parameter would be fine - all we're doing is getting the name of the concrete class and its package. We have no information about how it's being used. You seem to be leaping to conclusions here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, respectfully there two ways of doing this - pass it in or reference directly - both have issues to be aware of.  If the question doesn't have explicit details I think it's ok to consider the different situations and highlight potential issues with those.  I also think discussion in a wider context is useful/helpful.  I'd hardly call it jumping, let alone leaping, to conclusions.  Anyway the vote is in =)

Comment: @earcam: You've *stated* "This creates a circular dependency" with no caution about saying it *might* create a dependency or anything similar. I've seen no evidence at all about whether there's actually a circular dependency, so I'm sticking to my claim that you're jumping to conclusions. You seem to be assuming a particular kind of code behind this, when we haven't seen *any* code other than an abstract class and a concrete class extending it, which certainly isn't a circular dependency in itself. We don't even know where the code *using* the name of the plugin is.

Comment: @earcam If you define `abstract class Plugin { abstract String getPackageName(); }`, how would that violate the OCP or be a circular dependency? Dependencies are IMO exactly the same here - it's just explicitly declared instead of using functionality of `Object` and `Class`.

Comment: @zapl the same with your method: which ever collaborating class does the *wiring* will violate OCP **if** the OP ever needs to add another Plugin (and yes I'm "leaping to conclusions" yet again, except they're valid concerns).  Rather than counter my last comment Jon Skeet had to reiterate my mistaken assertion, which I'd already agreed with.  I'm starting to find the StackOverflow community needlessly aggressive and sanctimonious, hardly the place for debate, and increasingly not somewhere I wish to spend time.  (If you must have the final word, do so - I will not be returning to this page)

Comment: @earcam Sorry, was not meant that way. I misunderstood your concern and was thinking about the case where an instance of base class only wants to know it's own name to e.g. print log messages. Trying to gain knowledge about other instances or classes of other subtypes than the own is indeed problematic.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. A class has no knowledge of it's subclasses, and it should not have it.

Also, as @hexafraction pointed out: What if there are more than one subclass?

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you want *all* subclasses.

If so having your super class *know all* subclass implementations smells bad - it violates the [Open Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

You want an indirect method for obtaining these - for a standard Java solution try [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/spi/package-summary.html), then your Base class can look them up dynamically without coupling using a [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Otherwise, if you're using a nice supporting framework like OSGi then you can just register the plugins.